# Eyes won't stay on character when I move the rig

Tags: rigging

I'm quite new to Blender so I'm sorry if this is a very noob question but whenever I move the rig the eyes do not stay in my place and seem to rotate the other way. I've tried a lot of the suggested solutions online but they haven't fixed the issue (largely because I don't know what I'm doing haha).
[image: eye fell out oh no]

this is the blender file:
https://pasteall.org/blend/f55e1e764ada4b3fad38f0f8a2b78b96

Comment: Your armature is a mess.  You need to remove most of the armature modifiers, merge all of the different armatures into one armature (with CTRL-J), and then redo the parenting.

Comment: What method have you chosen for the eyes rigging?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select a eye and delete an Armature Modifier that connect with Armature.004.
2. Select Armature which control the eye.
3. Add Object Constraint > Child Of

   - Target : Armature.004
   - Bone : Head
   - Click Set Inverse
   - Influence : 1
4. Now you can rig your head bone and eyes will follow them. Don't forget to remove Child Of (Bone Constraint) in "eyelook" bone in Armature.005 that target at Armature.004
   [image: Remove Bone Constraint]

PS. As Marty said your armature is a mess, unorganized. This make it hard to work with and to find what the problem is.